# Problem with opening a website inside my app

Tags: java, android, mobile-website

The last weeks I've been using Android Studio to develop an app for my Uni, in which I have all the websites that my Uni requires together in an app and i don't have to search every single one on a browser.
After a few tests, I came to the conclusion that the best solution is to open/use the website inside my app,  instead of opening a browser to check my e-mails for example.
I found a way to open the websites inside my app but when it comes to "signing in" it finally uses a browser.
I am not that familiar with the program or Java so I thought of opening a thread in case anyone of you can help me solve my problem.

The function that I am curently using to open the website is :

```
    WebView webview = new WebView(this);
    setContentView(webview);
    webview.loadUrl(eclassURL);
```

FYI: eclassURL is the URL I am trying to open at case eclass.

PS1: This is my first thread, if anything else is needed, please don't hesitate to comment for more.
PS2: English is not my native language, so excuse my mistakes. :)

```
int main(void) {
printf("Thank you for your help!\n");
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Chrome Custom Tabs for this. You can find details about in this [link](https://developers.google.com/web/android/custom-tabs/implementation-guide).